# facebook like pulls and displays html tags on the wall

Tags: facebook, magento

I have a magento shop with facebook like button for every product. Facebook like button pulls and displays content from magento shop including html tags on the wall. I've managed to point it to the right image with meta "og:image", but this is a problem. Is it at least possible to make it to strip the tags or point it to somewhere else or pass the info directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can override what some of the og: tags are, such as og:url by specifying data-href attribute of the html5 tag.